# Dynamically generating html and js, unexpected quote generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
htmlStr+="<div class='list-group-item Specification' " +
"onClick=displayResults(" + key + ", '" + time + 
"', '" + fieldevents +     
"')>";
```

In Chrome debugger it generates the html I want, where

```
onclick=displayResults(1, '14:03', 'shotput, highjump, longjump')>
```

but in the elements tab I see that the generated html is

```
"onclick=displayResults(1," '14:03',
```

...where does the double quote after the first comma come from?  I am using chrome btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an attribute value contains spaces, it needs to be enclosed in quotes. Otherwise, the space ends the value.

```
htmlStr+="<div class='list-group-item Specification' " +
"onClick=\"displayResults(" + key + ", '" + time + 
"', '" + fieldevents +     
"')\">";
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the below code:

```
htmlStr += "<div class='list-group-item Specification' 
onClick='displayResults(" + key + ", '" + time + "', '" + fieldevents + "');'>";
```